# How do I overlay two plots in Julia

Tags: plot, statistics, julia

I would like to overlay these two plots. In my code, I only manage to plot them side by side.

```
using PyPlot
x = [μ, μ]
y = histogram(walks[end, :], bins=20, legend=nothing)

plot(plot(x), y)
```

[image]

Comment: Why is this tagged python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use the plotting functions with `!` versions.

For an example:

```
x = randn(100).*10 .+ 100;
using Plots
histogram(x, bins=10)
plot!(80:120, rand(1:25,41))
```

[image]